# Material UI v0 ListItem Alignment Issue when using Custom Avatar Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**Material UI version: v0.20.0**

I am trying to assign leftAvatar value via `CustomAvatar` component but it is not aligning as you can see in attached screenshot. Please help.

`CustomAvatar`: This component is working on some condition bases like if image is available the its

**MemberList/index.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import {List, ListItem} from 'material-ui/List';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import CustomAvatar from 'routes/CustomAvatar';

class MemberList extends Component {
    render(){<MuiThemeProvider> 
        <List>
            <ListItem 
                leftAvatar={<CustomAvatar avatarPic={false}/>}
                primaryText={"Mike Tailor"}
                secondaryText={"This is first text"}
                secondaryTextLines={1}
                rightIconButton={<IconMenu iconButtonElement={iconButtonElement}>
                  <MenuItem>Add friend</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem>Chat</MenuItem>              
                </IconMenu>}/>

            <ListItem 
                leftAvatar={<CustomAvatar avatarPic={true}/>}
                primaryText={"Kory Becker"}
                secondaryText={"This is second text"}
                secondaryTextLines={1}
                rightIconButton={<IconMenu iconButtonElement={iconButtonElement}>
                  <MenuItem>Add friend</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem>Chat</MenuItem>              
                </IconMenu>}/>
        </List>
    </MuiThemeProvider>}
}

export default withRouter(MemberList);
```

---

**CustomAvatar/index.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';

class CustomAvatar extends Component {
    render(){                               
        if(this.props.avatarPic){           
            return(<Avatar size={40} src={"http://www.example.com/myimage.png"} />) 
        }else{
           return(<Avatar size={40}>A</Avatar>)
        }       
    }
}

export default withRouter(CustomAvatar);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## The cause of your problem

Your problem is caused because the material-ui v0 library expects the `leftAvatar` prop to be an `Avatar` component, and so relies on internal values of `Avatar` behind the scenes. Since your `CustomAvatar` is not directly an `Avatar`, material-ui does not find these internals and so the styling does not work.

Specifically, if you take a look at the [source of `ListItem`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/src/List/ListItem.js), you'll notice a `pushElement` function that takes child components like `leftAvatar` and assigns styling by setting the `style` prop:

```
pushElement(children, element, baseStyles, additionalProps) {
  if (element) {
    const styles = Object.assign({}, baseStyles, element.props.style);
    children.push(
      React.cloneElement(element, {
        key: children.length,
        style: styles,
        ...additionalProps,
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Your `CustomAvatar` makes no use of this `style` prop, so you never receive the necessary CSS styling. That's the cause of your layout issues.

You have a couple of options to fix this depending on whether you are willing to upgrade to v1 or not.

## Code that fixes it

```
class CustomAvatar extends Component {
  render() {
    const { showPicture, ...other } = this.props;

    if (showPicture) {
      return (<Avatar size={40} {...other} src={"http://www.example.com/myimage.png"} />);
    } else {
      return (<Avatar size={40} {...other}>A</Avatar>);
    }
  }
}
```

As discussed above, the `pushElement` function sets the `style` prop. Right now, you're not using it, so your `Avatar`s get no styling. The `{...other}` spreads this prop down into your `Avatar`s so that they get the right styling and your layout works.

## But, you should upgrade to v1

v1 should have a stable release in the early quarters of 2018, and it fixes a lot of these kinds of problems. Instead of spending time working through these kinds of issues and working with v0, you should upgrade and learn the new (and, imho, improved) way.

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced same problem you could fix this by wrap your custom compoent into PAPER component of material-ui. Please see code below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import {List, ListItem} from 'material-ui/List';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import CustomAvatar from 'routes/CustomAvatar';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';


class MemberList extends Component {
    render(){<MuiThemeProvider> 
    <List>
        <ListItem 
            leftAvatar={<Paper zDepth={2} circle={true}><CustomAvatar avatarPic={false}/></Paper>}
            primaryText={"Mike Tailor"}
            secondaryText={"This is first text"}
            secondaryTextLines={1}
            rightIconButton={<IconMenu iconButtonElement={iconButtonElement}>
              <MenuItem>Add friend</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem>Chat</MenuItem>              
            </IconMenu>}/>

        <ListItem 
            leftAvatar={<Paper zDepth={2} circle={true}><CustomAvatar avatarPic={true}/></Paper>}
            primaryText={"Kory Becker"}
            secondaryText={"This is second text"}
            secondaryTextLines={1}
            rightIconButton={<IconMenu iconButtonElement={iconButtonElement}>
              <MenuItem>Add friend</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem>Chat</MenuItem>              
            </IconMenu>}/>
    </List>
</MuiThemeProvider>}
```

}

export default withRouter(MemberList);

Comment: Thanks Anil, Yes this make sense. Material UI v0 paper component solves me issue.